# Error: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred guice/java/spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, ubuntu, guice, cglib

I went to initialize a spring boot application when suddenly I got this Warning Message:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

I look around a little and found information about a bug in version 4.2.3 but fixed in 5.0.1.

My question is:

**Where and how may I manually install the guice dependencies, once the last version is not avaliable in command-line?**

The most updated version is 5.0.1 and I did not get this one with apt-update.

In one of my searches, I heard that I have to install it in google's directory...

I'm not sure about this and I think that I don't understand it very well.

My SO is Ubuntu Pop-OS 20.04, amd64x and I use Maven to manage the Spring Boot Project.

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot do you use? And which JDK do you use?

Comment: java11-openjdk-amd64 and Spring-boot 2.4.3

Comment: Seems there's a lib called guice in ../.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin/1iopthnavndlasol9gbrbg6bf2/apache-maven-3.6.3/lib/guice-4.2.3.jar

I try to substitute the file with the recent version downloaded from 
https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:guice

Testing it now. Later I'll bring it up some news

Comment: Do not do this because Maven 3.6.3 works without any modification with JDK7.....JDK15... so the question where exactly is the warning shown? Please show your pom file ....

Comment: Khmarbaise, thank you very much for your help. But I've decide to go to another path. I'm using native spring features, instead.
Anyway, there's a Ubuntu directory located in usr/share/java where you'll find the guice 4.2.1 and several Symbolic Links ponting to a source guice file configuration, which in turn, is used by M2 variable PATH.

I think that it was about downloading the new package (a.k.a guice-5.0.1) and Put it in share/java's directory and change all the simLinks that uses version 4.2.1.

But it will be a lot of work.
I simply give up. Is not worth it.

Comment: Ah first remove that M2 variable ... and precheck if you plain download the original apache dist from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and check if the same warning is comming up... because I fear the root cause is something else...